# GCP loading balancer always gets 400 invalid hostname to my IIS via IPV6

Tags: iis, google-cloud-platform, ipv6

As title, I have a IIS WebAPI on Compute Engine, always responses 400 Bad Request Invalid Hostname.

My API is just like:

*http://[2600:1905:0:6563::]:80/Hello/*

But I have another websocket program on Tomcat,and it works fine. So I guess the problem is on IIS?

Can't IIS recognize IPV6 format address or should I add some settings at somewhere?

Comment: Using address literals in URLs is strongly discouraged. The best practice is to create a hostname in DNS with an AAAA record pointing to your IPv6 address.

Comment: If this problem can solve by DNS,I'm glad to do that,thanks.

Comment: after I create DNS and AAAA record to my IPV6 Address this problem is no longer existed,thanks to Sander Steffann,you save me hours!

Comment: I'll put it in an answer so others can find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using address literals in URLs is strongly discouraged. The best practice is to create a hostname in DNS with an AAAA record pointing to your IPv6 address.